# Facing an issue to send IP to input class which is inside <div>

Tags: protractor

I tried these ... none of them worked, any hints pls ...

```
this.title = 'Diagnostic Tools';
it('should have a title', function() {

   browser.driver.get('https://URL');
   browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
   browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username')).sendKeys('user');
   browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys('pass123');
   browser.driver.findElement(by.name('login')).click();
   browser.waitForAngular();
   expect(browser.getTitle()).toContain('Diagnostic Tools');
   element(by.linkText("TOOLS")).click();
   element(by.name('server_ip')).sendKeys('1.1.1.1');

   });
});
```

Tried 3 ways after clicking "TOOLS". Adding sleep btw click & send also didn't help.

```
element(by.name('server_ip')).sendKeys('1.1.1.1');
element(by.cssContainingText('input[name="server_ip"]')).sendKeys('1.1.1.1');
element(by.css('server_ip')).sendKeys('1.1.1.1');
```

Input class:

```
<i><div class="form-group required ng-scope" ng-repeat="(param_key, param_value) in selectedTool.params">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label ng-binding">IP (s)</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input style="" required="required" pattern="[ ]*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])(.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])){3})( (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])(.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])){3})*[ ]*" 
class="form-control ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" 
name="server_ip" ng-model="toolInput[param_key]" ng-required="true" ng-attr-pattern="{{param_value.pattern}}" ng-attr-type="{{param_value.type}}" ng-attr-min="{{param_value.min}}" ng-attr-max="{{param_value.max}}" ng-attr-maxlength="{{param_value.maxlength}}">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <span class="help-block ng-binding">Can be multiple space separated ips.</span>
          </div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: getting error as : no element found using locator ...

Comment: Could you also show what code you have so far? (the complete test)

Comment: added complete code ...

Comment: @cmc try  browser.actions().click(element(by.css('input[name="server_ip"]'))).sendKeys('1.1.1.1').perform();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [explicitly wait](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) for the *element to be visible* prior to sending keys:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var serverIP = element(by.name("server_ip"));

browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(serverIP), 5000);
serverIP.sendKeys("1.1.1.1");
```

Comment: ThanQ alecxe, it worked :). But I have many & different elements like that, i.e input box, tables, multiple tables and logs lines. For every click do I need to add browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(serverIP), 5000);

Comment: ThanQ alecxe, it worked :). 1. But I have many & different elements like that, i.e input box, tables, multiple tables and logs lines. For every click do I need to add browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(serverIP), 5000);   2. And sometimes element get visible within 5000, some times it's more. In that case it fails with error "Failed: Wait timed out after Xms". Is there any solution for these 2 situations.